# I have created MySQL event to trigger sp daily, but my event is calling sp with one day gap. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Tags: mysql, events

Hi I have created a mysql event to trigger sp on daily basis but it is triggering the sp with one day gap. Event that I have created is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `JobdailyCalculationEvent` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS '2019-10-19 23:50:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
CALL sp_CalculateJob()
```

Please suggest me if any modification required in my event or if you have any other solution for the same.

thanks in advance.

Comment: 'it is triggering the sp with one day gap' - do you mean this runs once or once every other day?

Comment: For example if my event trigger sp on "18-11-2019 23:50" after this it is running on "20-11-2019 23:50" .

I want this to be run on everyday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please update your event and try this
Hopefully this will work for you:

```
DROP EVENT `JobDailyCalculationEvent`;
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `JobDailyCalculationEvent` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 
    HOUR STARTS '2019-10-19 23:50:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO CALL 
    sp_CalculateJob()
```